# How do I add labels properly to my pairs() plot?

Tags: r

I am trying to add labels to a pairs plot I've created using PCA data. There are two issues, the first being that when I add my labels, they seem to repeat across the different and don't follow the proper distribution of the data. The second is that when I add the labels, my points disappear.

My code is as follows:

```
#the data
project.pca <- prcomp(t(isometh))
minids =c("Sh3.2","Sh3.3","Sh11.1","Sh7.1","Sh7.2","Sh7.3","SNI10.1","SNI10.2","SNI20.2","SNI4.3","SNI6.1","SNI6.2")

#Pairs Plot
par(cex=1.0, cex.axis=0.8, cex.main=0.8)
pairs(project.pca$x[,1:6], 
      col = "black", 
      main = "Principal components analysis pairs-plot\nPCs 1-6", 
      pch = 16, 
      panel = function(x,...) { 
              text(project.pca$x, 
              labels = minids, 
              cex= 0.5, pos=3) 
              }
      )
```

project.pca

```
str(project.pca)
List of 5
 $ sdev    : num [1:12] 22.3 21.8 21.7 21.4 21.3 ...
 $ rotation: num [1:1072923, 1:12] 0.000324 -0.000354 0.000399 -0.000328 -0.001728 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : NULL
.. ..$ : chr [1:12] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
$ center  : num [1:1072923] 0.978 0.967 0.937 0.834 0.873 ...
$ scale   : logi FALSE
$ x       : num [1:12, 1:12] -32.323 -7.952 -4.466 -5.436 0.188 ...
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr [1:12] "M6-Sham-3.2" "M6-Sham-3.3" "M6-Sham11.1" "M6-Sham7.1" ...
.. ..$ : chr [1:12] "PC1" "PC2" "PC3" "PC4" ...
- attr(*, "class")= chr "prcomp"
```

[image: PCAwithpoints]
[image: PCAwithlabels]

edit: adding point and text as separate arguments produces the following:

```
par(cex=1.0, cex.axis=0.5, cex.main=0.5)
pairs(project.pca$x[,7:12], col="black", main="Principal components analysis pairs-plot\nPCs 7-12", pch=20)
points(project.pca$x, col="black", pch=20, cex=1)
text(project.pca$x, labels=ids, cex= 0.7, pos=3)
```

[image: PCA3]

Comment: I don't think you've constructed your panel function correctly (try to make it match the example in the documentation more closely). But it's hard to be of much more help with some actual data to work with.

Comment: The first line is not a complete R statement since it has 2 left parentheses and only 1 right. The title is "biplots", but `pairs()` does not produce biplots of pca analyses. A biplot combines the row and column plots in a single plot. You are just plotting xy plots or scatterplots. In your panel statement you do not ask for symbols, just text.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've edited the initial project.pca statement and the titles accordingly.

Comment: In the panels statement, how would I call for both text and points at the same time? I'm not sure how to format the function statement to include both points() and text() arguments at the same time.

@joran, what additional data would you need to see?

The original instructions I'm following are from this [link](https://www.biostars.org/p/282685/#282691)

Comment: `text()` and `points()` are separate functions that are supposed to be called separately. Typically, you do your `points()` call first and then `text()`. Each will draw on the plot in turn.

Comment: I have tried that, however it seems that the points get added but the text doesn't (see edit)